# Why does the factor of 1/2 appear in implicit summation of 2-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I've been watching some videos on differential forms, and I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bTp8gTJ-VE) brilliant chap. What confuses me is at about 6:12, he calls the other component redundant, and I'm confused what allows him to do so.

Consider two 1-forms, $\omega,\tau\in\Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, and then consider their wedge
\begin{align}
\epsilon & = \omega \wedge \tau\\
&= \omega_\mu \tau_\nu dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu \\
& = \epsilon_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu
\end{align}
using implicit summation. Expanding this sum,
$$
\epsilon = \epsilon_{11}dx^1 \wedge dx^1 + \epsilon_{12}dx^1 \wedge dx^2 + \epsilon_{21}dx^2 \wedge dx^1 + \epsilon_{22}dx^2 \wedge dx^2,
$$
but since these ($dx^\mu$) are $1$-forms, $dx^\mu \wedge dx^\mu = 0$, and $dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu = - dx^\nu \wedge dx^\mu $, so we may cut out two terms and reduce the others to
\begin{align}
\epsilon & = \epsilon_{12} dx^1 \wedge dx^2 + \epsilon_{21} dx^2 \wedge dx^1 \\
& = (\epsilon_{12} -\epsilon_{21})dx^1 \wedge dx^2.
\end{align}

Now, I know that this method (implicit summation) double counts, and hence the full expression reads $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu$ in the end, but ***why*** can I say that $\epsilon_{12}=-\epsilon_{21}$? I know that for an antisymmetric matrix this must be true, but what allows me to say this just from the mathematics of wedge products, and the properties of the coefficients?

Sorry if this is quite a rudimentary question, I'm just trying to get my head around it.

Comment: It is merely a convention. I stumbled in exactly the same trap a few weeks ago. See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/645515/curvature-2-forms-missing-factor-1-2-in-14-21-and-14-22-of-misner-thorne-a).

Comment: As Kurt said, it's just a convention. If you write an $n$-form as a sum over all monomials $dx^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_n}$, you count the same thing $n!$ times. If you require $i_1<\cdots<i_n$, then you have just the one term $dx^1\wedge\cdots \wedge dx^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ can be split into a symmetric part and an antisymmetric part:
$$
\epsilon_{\mu\nu} = \underbrace{\frac12(\epsilon_{\mu\nu}+\epsilon_{\nu\mu})}_{\text{symmetric}} + \underbrace{\frac12(\epsilon_{\mu\nu}-\epsilon_{\nu\mu})}_{\text{antisymmetric}}.
$$

When multiplied with the antisymmetric $dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu$ only the antisymmetric part of $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ contributes. The symmetric part cancels. Therefore it's convenient to let $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ be antisymmetric.